# Preprocessing of Labelled Text Data

Tags: python, data-structures, nlp, preprocessor, named-entity-recognition

To train NLP models for NER it is necessary to have text data that has named entity labels on the text. In many cases this is given by a character offset (eg.
`("Android Pay expands to Canada", [(0, 11, 'PRODUCT'), (23, 30, 'GPE')])`), BILUO format (eg. `(["Facebook", "released", "React", "in", "2014"], ["U-ORG", "O", "U-TECHNOLOGY", "O", "U-DATE"])`) or something similar (examples taken from the spaCy101). When one wants to do preprocessing on this data it is important to keeps the labels in the correct positions. Eg. for removing stop words or manipulating white-space characters and tokens will be removed. My question is:

> Is there a data structure that allows preprocessing of labelled text data while moving labels to the correct positions in the new text?

If there is already an implementation of this in python I would also be interested in this. Otherwise I might also be willing to code it up myself.

I used NER as a motivation for this question but I would also be interested if there was a more general data-structure that can store different types of labels simultaneously.

For example I would like to do some operation like this to make all of my document lower case.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
doc = nlp('Hello World! This is an amazing day!')
doc.text = doc.text.lower()
```

This is not possible and returning an error.

`AttributeError: attribute 'text' of 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' objects is not writable`

Comment: If Spacy's tokenizer meets your needs, I believe its [`Token`](https://spacy.io/api/token) class keeps track of the indices of each token within the original document, which should help with aligning the labels. Might be a good starting point if you get stuck, at the very least.

Comment: I think spacy Docs and Tokens are not meant to be modified after they are created. An easy example I already did not manage to easily get done was changing all text to lower case.

Comment: Could you give more details or an example of what goes wrong? (Just to make sure I'm understanding everything right.)

Comment: I have added an example of a operation I would like to do on this kind of objects to the question. But I don't only want to be able to switch to lower case. Optimally I want to be able to make all standard text preprocessing operations (removal of stop words, lemmatisation, stemming, white-space cleaning, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, spaCy is designed so that its [`Token`](https://spacy.io/api/token) class keeps track of the character offsets relative to the original document (see e.g., `token.idx`).

This will still be handled if you need to do some custom preprocessing. For instance, if you take the example from [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers):

```
print([t.idx for t in doc])
```

which should give you:

```
['hello', '-', 'world.', ':)']
[0, 5, 6, 13]
```

If you really want or need to have your own custom attributes, spaCy allows you to set custom attributes and methods via the `._` namespace, which you can read more about [here](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes).

Hopefully one of those options meets your needs. If not, you can maybe look to spaCy's source code and documentation for inspiration?

#### Edit 1: Example

```py
import spacy


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text = "Sam is going to the store."

labels = [(0, 3, "PER"),
          (20, 25, "LOC")]

extra_stopwords = ['hi']

for word in extra_stopwords:
    nlp.vocab[word].is_stop = True

doc = nlp(text)

# add Span(start, end, label) to doc.ents
for start, end, label in labels:
    span = doc.char_span(start, end, label)

    # I forgot char_span only assigns the label to the span
    # might be safer to use the ._ namespace I mentioned earlier
    # instead of .ent_type_, but the idea should be the same
    for token in span:
        token.ent_type_ = label

# examples of things you can access
print([(token,
        token.ent_type_,
        token.lemma_.lower(),
        token.is_stop)
      for token in doc])
```

#### Edit 2:

If you really want to get the shifted offsets, you can use the above and loop through the tokens, keeping track of where you are, and construct a new `Doc` object out of that. You'd have to decide how you want to handle adding the whitespace back in; I just used a naive approach below for simplicity.

```py
from spacy.tokens import Doc


# example
def preprocessing(token):
    """Takes a token and returns the processed string."""
    return token.lemma_.lower()


labels_new = []
words = []
spaces = []
offset = 0


for i, token in enumerate(doc):
    token_new = preprocessing(token)
    words.append(token_new)

    if token.ent_type_:
        labels_new.append((offset,
                           offset + len(token_new),
                           token.ent_type_))

    offset += len(token_new)

    if len(token.whitespace_) == 1:
        spaces.append(True)

    else:
        spaces.append(False)


doc_new = Doc(nlp.vocab, words, spaces)
```

Then you'll have:

```py
print([(token, token.idx) for token in doc_new])

# [(sam, 0), (be, 4), (go, 7), (to, 10), (the, 13), (store, 17), (., 22)]
```

and:

```py
print(labels_new)

# [(0, 3, 'PER'), (12, 17, 'LOC')]
```

(You'll have to reassign these to each token as before, of course.)

Comment: The thing is that I want to start with labelled data and then do the preprocessing. The used case would: I have a dataset of labelled text. Now I want to load these texts and do some preprocessing on it to bring it to a standard format. For labelling I took the original text. In my code I now want to change the text while still keeping the labels in the correct positions. I don't see how your proposal can do this.

Comment: I added an example, not totally sure if you have a more specific need that that can't cover?

Comment: Maybe I should have specified "correct position" in my question better. I want to modify the text such that I get a new text with the labels on the new positions. Eg. a modified doc where I can call doc.text to get the new text and token.idx to get the index in that new text.

Comment: I understand, I'm just having trouble envisioning the motivation for doing such a thing. If the goal is to get the (start, end, label) spans paired up with the appropriate processed token, you already have that with `token`/`token.ent_type_`. Needing to know the "processed" character offsets seems unusual to me, which is why I'm curious about the motivation.

Comment: I want to use the modified document as training data for an other model.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you can still use the original `token`, `label` pairs from the original snippet to "realign" the labels, if you really want, it just takes a loop through the tokens. (I added an example above of how you might do this, hopefully it the sort of thing you're looking for, or at least a good starting point.)